# ERROR of showing the result in JButton

Tags: java

As these code in the following, i am going to create a JButton on North, which will change the sentance when I click it, and there are some problems that, the word wont change after I clicked! And also, the frame shown after I ran the problem(test), the square and the North text bar (JButton) was disappeared! I should pull the window larger, then the bar and the square will come out again!

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton clickButton;
    GrowAndShrinkListener listener;

    public class SquareDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        int squareSize = 100;
        int width = frame.getWidth();
        int height = frame.getHeight();

        public SquareDrawPanel() {
            super();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(getWidth() / 2 - squareSize / 2,
                    getHeight() / 2 - squareSize / 2,
                    squareSize, squareSize);
        }
    }

    public class GrowAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {
        GrowAndShrinkListener(JButton button) {
            button = new JButton("Click me to grow the Square");
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            button.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JButton) {
                clickButton = (JButton) source;
                clickButton.setText("Click to shrink square");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI test = new GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI();
        test.go();
    }

    private void createListenerButton() {
        listener = new GrowAndShrinkListener(clickButton);
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SquareDrawPanel squareDraw = new SquareDrawPanel();
        createListenerButton();
        Container cpane = frame.getContentPane();
        cpane.add(squareDraw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // 5) set JButton to show text
        clickButton = new JButton("Click me to grow the square"); 
        cpane.add(clickButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at your code formatting!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are creating the button after you assign the listener. Move the `createListenerButton()` call to the last line inside `go()`.

```
public void go() {
    // ...
    clickButton = new JButton("Click me to grow the square");
    cpane.add(clickButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    createListenerButton();
   // ...
}
```

Also looks like you are adding the button twice. You are making this too complicated.

```
public class GrowAndShrinkListener // ...
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    // ....
}

public void go() // ...
    cpane.add(clickButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    // ....
}
```

Try the following:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton clickButton;
    private GrowAndShrinkListener listener;

    public class SquareDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        int squareSize = 100;
        int width = frame.getWidth();
        int height = frame.getHeight();

        public SquareDrawPanel() {
            super();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(getWidth() / 2 - squareSize / 2, getHeight() / 2
                    - squareSize / 2, squareSize, squareSize);
        }
    }

    public class GrowAndShrinkListener implements ActionListener {
        private JButton button;

        public GrowAndShrinkListener(JButton button) {
            this.button = button;
            this.button.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JButton && ((JButton) source) == button) {
                button.setText("Click to shrink square");
            }
        }
    }

    private void createListenerButton(JButton button) {
        listener = new GrowAndShrinkListener(button);
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SquareDrawPanel squareDraw = new SquareDrawPanel();
        Container cpane = frame.getContentPane();
        cpane.add(squareDraw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // 5) set JButton to show text
        clickButton = new JButton("Click me to grow the square");
        cpane.add(clickButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        createListenerButton(clickButton);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI test = new GrowAndShrinkSquareGUI();
                test.go();
            }
        });
    }
}
```